# Is it possible to read a docx file content in the browser?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, docx

I want to upload multiple Docx files and then read the content of each file and extract information from them to add it to the collection in the backend.
Is it possible to read a word file in the browser? and get the content?

Any help is appreciated.
if you think I should not process these files in the browser please suggest some other option to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in a browser, but you can do it on the web server using third party tools like Office Writer or Aspose.